# How to disable fields in list newform.aspx/editform.aspx using javascript/Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Need to disable *Managed metadata* field (the below code disables the textbox of the field but not the button which is used to select the value to the field), *Choice field with radio buttons or checkboxes* in the newform.aspx/editform.aspx of a list using javascript/jquery.

I'm using the below code, it disable all other fields except the above-mentioned type of fields,

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
 function disableField () 
{$("[title='fieldName']").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('background-color', '#F6F6F6');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("disableField");
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for [Set Choice Field as Read Only in SharePoint](http://itcore.devoworx.net/read-only-choice-field-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("[title='fieldName']")
```

Above selector does not match Choice field with radio buttons or checkboxes.

So it's time to dig into the html of `newform.aspx`/`editform.aspx`.

Have a look on the following html of choice field.

```
<table id="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #1"><input id="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" checked="checked"><label for="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_0">Enter Choice #1</label></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #2"><input id="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_1" type="checkbox"><label for="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_1">Enter Choice #2</label></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span class="ms-RadioText" title="Enter Choice #3"><input id="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_2" type="checkbox"><label for="Choices_a3f7dc5c-38a9-4aa6-b8dc-d5c786bded0b_MultiChoiceOption_2">Enter Choice #3</label></span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So now you can apply following js to disable it.

```
(function(){
  var allChoices = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=Choices]');
  [].forEach.call(allChoices, function(node){
    node.disabled = "disabled";
  });
})();
```

If you wish to use above code, then do not forget to replace `Choices` by your field name.

See result in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cicunerapi/edit?html,js,console,output)

For Managed metadata do the same thing. Find html from browser and then write some js to hide them.

Comment: Thanks, Atish it was really helpful, What about for Managed Metadata field.?

Comment: Did not dig into that yet. My suggestion is same. find the html from browser. then write some js to hide. if you stuck, let me know I will help.

Comment: Careful this caused side effects for me, the field could not  be saved after a save in edit form !!!!